# Chinese input methods not working in ubuntu mate 19.10

Tags: mate, language-support, ibus, chinese

I had chinese input working on my ubuntu mate 18.04 desktop, and after updating to 19.10, the chinese input is broken.

I've installed all the ibus and pinyin packages, and the hot keys indicate that I'm switching between English and intelligent pinyin, but typing "ni hao" does not bring up a menu of chinese characters.

It's as though everything is working, except the input method.

Edit 2: I wonder how our installs differ in these packages...

```
jjs@baron:~$ dpkg -l |grep -e ibus -e pinyin | sort -u
ii  fcitx-module-cloudpinyin:amd64         0.3.6-2                             amd64        Flexible Input Method Framework - cloudpinyin module
ii  fcitx-pinyin                           1:4.2.9.6-5build1                   amd64        Flexible Input Method Framework - classic Pinyin engine
ii  fcitx-sunpinyin:amd64                  0.4.2-2                             amd64        fcitx wrapper for Sunpinyin IM engine
ii  gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64                  1.5.21-1~exp2ubuntu2                amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - introspection data
ii  ibus                                   1.5.21-1~exp2ubuntu2                amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-data                              1.5.21-1~exp2ubuntu2                all          Intelligent Input Bus - data files
ii  ibus-libpinyin                         1.11.0-1ubuntu1                     amd64        Intelligent Pinyin engine based on libpinyin for IBus
ii  ibus-pinyin                            1.5.0-5                             amd64        Pinyin engine for IBus
ii  libgusb2:amd64                         0.3.0-1                             amd64        GLib wrapper around libusb1
ii  libibus-1.0-5:amd64                    1.5.21-1~exp2ubuntu2                amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
ii  libpinyin13:amd64                      2.3.0-1                             amd64        library to deal with PinYin
ii  libpinyin-data:amd64                   2.3.0-1                             amd64        Data for PinYin / zhuyin input method library
ii  libsunpinyin3v5:amd64                  3.0.0~rc1+ds1-2                     amd64        Simplified Chinese Input Method from SUN (runtime)
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64                     2:1.0.23-1                          amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusbmuxd4:amd64                      1.1.0~git20181007.07a493a-1         amd64        USB multiplexor daemon for iPhone and iPod Touch devices - library
ii  sunpinyin-data:amd64                   0.1.22+20170109-2                   amd64        Statistical language model data from open-gram
jjs@baron:~$
```

Comment: I tested IBus on Ubuntu MATE 19.10 about 10 minutes ago, and it worked fine. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this command: `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'`

Comment: Btw, since you are using `ibus-libpinyin` you may want to clear the user cache: `rm ~/.cache/ibus/libpinyin/*`

Comment: I'm curious if there is some missing package, or if having more than one input method installed is a problem. For some reason, fcixt is installed by default

Comment: Having `fcitx` installed should not be a problem, and the output from the command I asked you to run looks good. Did you try to clear the cache as I suggested?

Comment: cache cleared, as suggested. logged out and logged back in. But for some reason, typing still does not bring up a list of Chinese characters to match

Comment: You should install the `ibus-gtk` and `ibus-gtk3` packages.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. After installing ibus-gtk and ibus-gtk3, 我成功了！

Answer (score 0):

I also lost CJK input when upgrading to 19.10. The upgrade was interrupted by a system crash, requiring a boot into safe mode, and repairing broken packages. It turns out that none of the ibus modules for pinyin, hangeul, and kana/kanji support got installed.